# SQL raw query in laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a working **SQL** query.

```
SELECT stuid,grade,SUM(full_amount) FROM due_payments group by stuid having SUM(full_amount) !=15600
```

This is working fine in **MySQL** workbench and **phpmyadmin**,But i cant seems to get this work in **Laravel 5.3**

I tried this on Laravel app with no Luck

```
$someVariable = Input::get(15600);

$results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT stuid,grade,SUM(full_amount) FROM due_payments 
                group by stuid having SUM(full_amount) =:somevariable)", array(
        'somevariable' => $someVariable,
)));
```

Can someone Help me with this.Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if all Input::get() doesn't take value as argument but the **element name**
`$someVariable = Input::get(15600);`
You can just use `$someVariable = 15600;`

Then use *Query Builder* rather than *Raw SQL query*

```
     $results = DB::table('due_payments')
     ->select(array('stuid', 'grade', DB::raw('SUM(full_amount)'))) 
     ->groupBy('stuid')
     ->havingRaw('SUM(full_amount) != '.$someVariable)
     ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `query builder`.

```
$results = DB::table('due_payments')
        ->select('stuid', 'grade',DB::raw('SUM(full_amount)'))
        ->groupBy('stuid')
        ->havingRaw('SUM(full_amount) != 15600')
        ->get();
```

Comment: glad it helps :)